# Htaccess Rules not working on my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I copied this code from other answer on stackoverflow, I want to shorten a long url :

for example

http://example.com/mobile/user.php?uname=foo

to

http://example.com/foo

here is my current code :

```
Rewriteengine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/mobile/user.php\?uname=(.*).*$ 
RewriteRule . /mobile/%1 [R,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mobile/user.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
```

It is showing a wired url in browser

```
 http://example.com/mobile/fooHTTP 1.1
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Rewriteengine on 
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/mobile/user.php\?uname=(.*?).*$ 
 RewriteRule . /mobile/%1 [R,L] 
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /mobile/user.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
```

This is happening because Star(*) is 
 **[greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html)** 
 in Regex so it consumes as much as possible. And this behaviour can be changed simply by putting a **?** after the star.

```
(.*?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong in first rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mobile/user\.php\?uname=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /mobile/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mobile/user.php?uname=$1 [R,L]
```